# Reading Multimap with composite key including null field

Tags: java, collections, guava, multimap

I have a `Multimap` to store some data with composite key (data type, data id).
Here is my code:

```
public class Data {

    private final String type;

    private final Integer id;

    private final String information;

    public Data(String type, Integer id, String information) {
        this.type = type;
        this.id = id;
        this.information = information;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Type: " + type + ", ID: " + id + ", Info: " + information;      
    }

}

public class Test {

    private static Multimap<Key, Data> data = HashMultimap.create();

    static class Key {

        private final String type;

        private final Integer id;

        public Key(String type, Integer id) {
            this.type = type;
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            //System.out.println("in hashcode");
            return Objects.hashCode(type);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            //System.out.println("in equals");
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }

            if (!(obj instanceof Key)) {
                return false;
            }

            Key other = (Key) obj;
            if (other.type.equals(type)) {
                if (other.id == null) {  // Return true for null ID Data
                    return true;
                } else if (other.id.equals(id)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

    }

    private static void addData(String type, Integer id, String information) {
        data.put(new Key(type, id), new Data(type, id, information));
    }

    private static void printData(String type, Integer id) {
        System.out.println("\n===============");
        System.out.println("Filtered Data for: Type => " + type + ", ID => " + id);
        for (Data d : data.get(new Key(type, id))) {
            System.out.println(d);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addData("confidential", 11, "Some Confidential Data!");
        addData("private", 21, "Some Private Data!");
        addData("government", 13, "Some Govt. Data!");

        addData("public", null, "Some public data!");
        addData("public", 26, "Another public data!");
        addData("public", 4, "More public information!");

        addData("unspecified", null, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!");
        addData("unspecified", 15, "consectetur adipiscing elit.");
        addData("unspecified", 25, "Integer sed velit vel.");
        addData("unspecified", null, "In vitae velit consequat");       

        printData("unspecified", 25);
        printData("public", 26);
    }

}
```

Now, I want to filter this data by `Data::type` & `Data::id`, including data whose `Data::type` matches but `Data::id` is `null`.

**Expected Output:**

```
===============
Filtered Data for: Type => unspecified, ID => 25
Type: unspecified, ID: null, Info: In vitae velit consequat
Type: unspecified, ID: null, Info: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!
Type: unspecified, ID: 25, Info: Integer sed velit vel.

===============
Filtered Data for: Type => public, ID => 26
Type: public, ID: null, Info: Some public data!
Type: public, ID: 26, Info: Another public data!
```

**Actual Output**

```
===============
Filtered Data for: Type => unspecified, ID => 25
Type: unspecified, ID: null, Info: In vitae velit consequat
Type: unspecified, ID: 15, Info: consectetur adipiscing elit.
Type: unspecified, ID: null, Info: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!
Type: unspecified, ID: 25, Info: Integer sed velit vel.

===============
Filtered Data for: Type => public, ID => 26
Type: public, ID: 4, Info: More public information!
Type: public, ID: null, Info: Some public data!
Type: public, ID: 26, Info: Another public data!
```

For this purpose, I've implemented `hashCode()` & `equals()` methods in `Key` class and returned `true` when other data object `id` is `null`.

---

**Questions:**

1. Am I using the correct approach or this can be implemented using simple `Map`?
2. Why `hashCode` & `equals` methods are called only once, when I call `Multimap::get()` method? (According to me, each key in map should've matched with the specified key!)
3. If it's the correct approach, how to implement `equals` method to get expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the hash map to work properly, the equals implementation must satisfy the constraint that if `a.equals(b)` and `b.equals(c)` then it must be true that `a.equals(c)`. If you break that constraint then the map will behave unpredictably. This property is called transitivity. See the full list of constraints on equals implementations [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

To do what you want you must do two lookups in the `printData` method, one with `new Key(type, id)` and one with `new Key(type, null)`. There is no shortcut with clever equals implementations.

To answer the question, why are you seeing `hashCode` and `equals` called only once when you call `get()`? This is another consequence of that constraint on `equals`. The map has already determined that `Key(x, 15)` and `Key(x, null)` are the same, according to your `equals` implementation. This was done when you inserted the data. So on lookup it only has to compare against one of them and then it assumes the other will also match.

Comment: I'll try it. Can you explain, why equals & hashCode method is only called once? When data.get() is called in printData() method.

Comment: Yeah, two lookups did it! I think, that one should not define clever equals implementations as it can lead to unpredictable results.

Comment: Ok, now I got it, when these are called when adding values to the map!